# How to speed up my python dictionary loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop

I have a a dataframe and a nested dictionary.  I need to match keys in the dictionary to names of the columns of the dataframe, and append a column containing the right value of said dictionary.  The ultimate value is either two or three deep within the dictionary.  However, this loop has been running for two days.  I think my loops are not efficient. Could anyone take a quick look at this syntax and spot any inefficiencies?

```
   for index, row in df.iterrows():
        for k1, v1 in model_4_factors.items():
            for k2, v2 in v1.items():
                if isinstance(v2, dict):
                    for k3, v3 in v2.items():
                        if k2 == row['RATING_CLASS_CODE'] and k3 == row['unit_value_model']:
                            df['value_factor_4'] = v3
                        elif k2 == row['RATING_CLASS_CODE'] and k3 == row['MVEH_CC_Model']:
                            df['cc_factor_4'] = v3
                        elif k2 == row['term_model'] and k3 == row['advanced_purchase_days_model']:
                            df['advanced_days_factor_4'] = v3
                        elif k2 == row['marital_status_model'] and k3 == row['Driver_Age_model']:
                            df['driver_age_factor_4'] = v3
                        else:
                            df['value_factor_4'] = None

                else:
                    if row['mveh_pkg_typ_cd'] == k2:
                        df['mveh_pkg_typ_cd_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['CLded'] == k2:
                        df['CLded_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['unit_drv_exp_model'] == k2:
                        df['unit_drv_exp_model'] = v2

                    elif row['v_age_model'] == k2:
                        df['v_age_model_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['years_owned_model'] == k2:
                        df['years_owned_model_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['FIN_RESP_CD'] == k2:
                        df['FIN_RESP_CD_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['st_ad_moto_safety_course'] == k2:
                        df['st_ad_moto_safety_course_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['st_ai_instructor_course'] == k2:
                        df['st_ai_instructor_course_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['st_ci_instructor_course'] == k2:
                        df['st_ci_instructor_course_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['st_mf_moto_safety_course '] == k2:
                        df['st_mf_moto_safety_course_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['st_mi_instructor_course'] == k2:
                        df['st_mi_instructor_course_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['st_mc_moto_safety_course'] == k2:
                        df['st_mc_moto_safety_course_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['st_rc_moto_safety_course'] == k2:
                        df['st_rc_moto_safety_course_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['st_ri_instructor_course'] == k2:
                        df['st_ri_instructor_course_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['ds_pn_prior_insurance'] == k2:
                        df['ds_pn_prior_insurance_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['st_rc_moto_safety_course'] == k2:
                        df['st_rc_moto_safety_course_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['Loyalty'] == k2:
                        df['Loyalty_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['ds_mc_motorcycle_endorsement'] == k2:
                        df['ds_mc_motorcycle_endorsement_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['multi_unit_model2'] == k2:
                        df['multi_unit_model2_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['ds_ad_affinity'] == k2:
                        df['ds_ad_affinity_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['ds_ak_alliance'] == k2:
                        df['ds_ak_alliance_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['multi_policy_count_model'] == k2:
                        df['multi_policy_count_model_factor_4'] = v2

                    elif row['ds_fp_paid_in_full'] == k2:
                        df['ds_fp_paid_in_full_factor_4'] = v2

                    else:
                        pass
```

The data frame is about 800,000 rows.  The dictionary is a large code block as well.  Sample from dictionary and DF below.  `factors' is the dictionary I'm working with.`df_result` is what I want in the end minus the order of the columns.

```
import pandas as pd

vn_value = {23000: 1, 30000: 2, 26000: 3}
g_cn_value = {2000:1, 3000: 2, 4000: 3}
la_value = {19000: .5, 20000: 1, 20500: 1.2}
unit_value_factors = {'VN':vn_value, 'G_CN':g_cn_value, 'LA':la_value}
package = {'VPN':.3, 'SPS':.5, 'LSS':.7, 'SCE':.8}
d_cc = {1700: 1.3, 1800:2.1}
E_cc = {1300:1.8, 1400:.6}
HD_cc = {1400:1.5, 1800:1.7, 1900:1.8}
cc_factors = {'D':d_cc, 'E':E_cc, 'HD':HD_cc}

factors = {'value_class':unit_value_factors, 'package_modifier':package, 'cc_class':cc_factors}



df_value_class = ['VN', 'VN', 'G_CN', 'LA']
df_value = [26000, 30000, 3000, 19000]
df_package = ['VPN', 'SPS', 'LSS', 'SCE']
df_cc_class = ['D', 'E', 'HD', 'HD']
df_cc = [1700, 1300, 1400, 1900]

value_factor = [3,2,2,.5]
package_factor = [.3, .5 ,.7, .8]
cc_factor = [1.3, 1.8, 1.5, 1.8]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value_class':df_value_class, 'value':df_value, 'package_modifier':df_package
                   , 'cc_class':df_cc_class, 'cc':df_cc, 'AI':df_sc_AI, 'MS':df_sc_MS})


df_result = pd.DataFrame({'value_class':df_value_class, 'value':df_value, 'value_answer':value_factor
                          , 'package_modifier':df_package, 'package_answer':package_factor, 'cc_class':df_cc_class
                          , 'cc':df_cc, 'cc_answer':cc_factor})

df_result['score'] = df_result['value_answer']*df_result['package_answer'] * df_result['cc_answer']
```

Comment: You can use a dictionary (outside the loops) to map `row`'s keys to `df`'s keys.

Comment: depending on your data complexity you could have a `n**4` complexity. you have four embeded for loops. can't you just lookup since you have dicts?

Comment: Thank you @meowgoesthedog.  I'm not sure I follow. Do you mean develop another dictionary?

Comment: Hi @NathanMcCoy.  I'm not sure what you mean by `lookup`.  I'm new to using dictionaries.

Comment: This is unreadable. Take a step back and include your dictionary and dataframe and explain what you expect as output.

Comment: @Erfan.  Question updated with example.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. your question is to speed things up. the reason for this is the embedded for loops. try using a `key` to get what you want

Comment: @NathanMcCoy.  `df_result` is what I'm trying to do.  The for-loop was the only way I know how.  The 'key' in the first level of the dictionary matches column names.  The second level is the possible values in the corresponding df and the the dict values that match those df values should be appended.

Comment: for the key-value pairs that are there nested three levels deep, the second level key will match another column, and the third level key will match the values, appending the corresponding dict value in another column.

Comment: In dictionaries you can get value corresponding to a key in constant time `value=dict[key]`. This is what he meant by lookup. You don't have to break them line by line and compare. It csn look smth like `if column_name in factor_dict: df[columnname+"_factor] = factor_dict[column_name][df[column_name]][df[other_column]]` . This is not a working code, just something to get you going in a correct direction. If you know the rules of column naming then you can set it up to react in case of dictionaries of varying depth, but I'd suggest you make 2 dictionaries, one with flat values other with nested

Comment: Thanks @IcedLance.  Figured it out.  See answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This is much faster.

```
for column in columns:
    for key, value in model_4_factors.items():
        if column == key:
            df[column+'_factor_4'] = df[key].map(value)
```

Comment: @icedlance hit the nail on the head, looks like it worked